# Is there anyway to automatically replace a section of a string in Python using a list of values?

Tags: python, list

If I have a string for example:

```
value = ("The value is at $500.00 today, check again please.")
```

And I have a table (df or list or something) of values, would it be possible to replace the "$500.00" at a set interval or whenever the script runs?

For example, if tomorrows value was $650.00 and so on, then without changing the string manually, could I keep replacing that segment of the string?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

There is multiple ways to solve your problem!

If you search for "Python string formatting" you will find a lot of examples etc.

```
value = "$500"

# one way
message = "The value is at %s today, check again please."

print(message % value)

# another way
message2 = "The value is at {0} today, check again please."
print(message2.format(value))
```

If your value is actually an `int` you can deal with it by converting your int to a `str` first.

```
value = 500
message = "The value is at $%s today, check again please."
print(message % str(value))
```

Answer (score 0):

Python 3's f-Strings offer an even better syntax for this:

```
value = 500.00
message = f'The value is at ${value} today, check again please.'
print(message)
# output: The value is at $500.0 today, check again please.
```

Read more about Python3 fstrings [here](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/).

Answer (score 0):

you could use `str.format`:

```
my_list = ['$500.00', '$600.00']
value = "The value is at {} today, check again please."

print(value.format(my_list[0]))
print(value.format(my_list[1]))
```

output:

```
The value is at $500.00 today, check again please.
The value is at $600.00 today, check again please.
```